# Single quotes in AngularJS tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have the following email validation code that uses the ng-pattern directive. I need to include single quotes in the error validation so that for example: asd'f@dfs.com fails. I don't want to use the default angular directive because subsequent .. (dots), ^, commas etc not catered for

```
<input type="email" name="username" placeholder="jasdf@asdf.com" ng-model="user.username" ng-maxlength="100" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: blur }" ng-pattern='/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.\,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;^:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/' required />
        <div class="error-container" ng-show="userForm.username.$dirty && userForm.username.$error">
          <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.username.$error.required">
               Your email is required.
        </small>
          <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.username.$error.pattern">
               Please input a valid email.
        </small>
          <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength">
              Your email cannot be longer than 100 characters
        </small>
```

It can be seen from the above that I'm using the following Regex: `ng-pattern='/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.\,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;^:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/'`

My question is how do I include single quotes (') so that it doesn't clash with the ng-pattern tag quotes and also (^) in the Regex. I searched around and it seems I should use &apos but not sure how to implement. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `\x27` instead of a `'`, and `\x22` instead of a `"`. Do you really have trouble with `^`, too?  Use `\x5E`.

Comment: Why not using the build in email validation? http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcQN0WYSoU1gogFo5nic?p=preview

Comment: I will say, better to create ur custom directive here. Don't use complex pattern on ur html page, if u need to use email validation on more than one pages

Comment: Follow-up to my first comment: try `ng-pattern="/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\x22]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;^:\s@\x22]+)*)|(\x22[^@]+\x22))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}])|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/"`

Comment: @AfshinGhazi: Have you had a chance to check the regex I suggest?

Comment: @WiktorStrib Thanks, the ^ has been added but the ' (single quote) still doesn't fails the validation if put before the @ sign.

Comment: @FarazShuja:  I would prefer to avoid the custom directive and the validation is only used in a popup.

Comment: @Jossef Harush: The built-in validation doesn't cater for many characters.

Comment: Do you want the scenario when the `'` appears before the `@` to fail? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW8fQ2/2) (I did not include `\x27` in the previous demo).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks for the effort. The second link is good as it fails when a single quote is inserted but then the ^ does not fail.

Comment: I think I understand it now :) Try [`^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@^\x22\x27]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;^:\s@\x22\x27]+)*)|(\x22[^‌​@]+\x22))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}])|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$`](https://regex101.com/r/uW8fQ2/3) - I added the `^` to the first negated character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this a bit shortened version:

```
ng-pattern="/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@^\x22\x27]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;^:\s@\x22\x27]+)*)|(\x22[^‌​@‌​]+\x22))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}])|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/"
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW8fQ2/3)

The changes are:

- Three `\.[0-9]{1,3}` are contracted since it is repeated 3 times to `(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}`
- The first and second negated character classes now contain `\x27` (`'`) and `\x22` (`"`) symbols
- Also added `^` to the first negated character class
- `\x22.+\x22` is turned to `\x22[^‌​@‌​]+\x22` so that we do not overflow to the domain part and stay within the username part.